# Where to find all spectroscopic data about 28 CMa?

Tags: star, spectroscopy, data-analysis

I am searching all available spectroscopic data (and particularly wavelength interval) of 28 CMa in the constellation Canis Majoris to measure radial velocities. Which database should I use?

Comment: 28 CMa from the constalation of Canis Majoris

Comment: Elena, your question has been flagged for closure because it lacks sufficient detail to clarify the problem. Adding a further explanation *in a comment* isn't enough, since the assessment is made on the question itself. I'll add the information you've provided (and fix the spelling/grammar issues), but "which database should I use" invites subjective opinion, which is also a reason for closure. Can you [edit] your post to provide greater focus, e.g. what you will use the data for? If possible, try also to rephrase your question so that there's a *definitive answer*. See also [ask]. :-)

Comment: I added the purpose.

Comment: http://cdsportal.u-strasbg.fr/?target=*%20ome%20CMa   (you need to cut and paste all of this)

Comment: Thank you very much and how to find spectra there?